# Change mxGraphModel of current mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, draw.io

I would like to change the model of the current graph displayed.

With Java (JGraph) I can use graph.setModel(...) but there is no such method in JavaScript. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [graph.model](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.model) directly

Comment: Thank you @David, maybe we are doing something wrong but when doing this the cells from the old model are still displayed (but are not present is the model).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the graph by either calling

```
graph.removeCells(graph.getChildVertices(graph.getDefaultParent()));
```

or

```
graph.getModel().clear();
```

and setting a new model afterwards.
In my experience, you have to additionally remove the html of the graph container, to truly erase all content (otherwise you get some weird white space in there).

```
$("#container").html("");
```